# Laravel event cannot get data from model relationship using load() method

Tags: laravel, laravel-echo, laravel-events

I cannot get the data from the `model` with a relationship. But when I use `return response()->json($chat->load('attachments'))` I can get the attachments.

I want to get data `Chat` data with the `attachments`.

This is my Model `Chat.php`

```
class Chat extends Model
{
    public function attachments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ChatAttachment');
    }
}
```

And this is my controller `Chat.php`

```
public function storeMessage(Request $request)
{
    DB::transaction(function() use ($request) {
        $chat = new Chat;
        $chat->message = $request->message;
        $chat->save();

        event( new GetMessages($chat->load('attachments')));
    }, 2);
}
```

My event `GetMessages.php`

```
class GetMessages implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $chats;
    public function __construct($chats)
    {
        $this->chats = $chats;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
      return ['get-messages'];
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
      return 'get-messages';
    }
}
```

And my JS

```
Echo.channel('get-messages').listen('.get-messages', (data) => {
    console.log(data.chats) // Can see the chats object, but no attachments
    console.log(data.chats.attachments); // Undefined
})
```

Comment: Could you explain the question?.  `$chat->load('attachments');`
this is correct way of loading a relationship

Comment: show where you are trying to get this data and what is happening that isn't what you expect

Comment: @Aashishgaba, Yes, but not working inside the event.

Comment: @lagbox, I want to return data `Chat` with the `attachments` in Event